# Generate RSA Key pair and signature in iOS same as Android

Tags: java, android, ios, swift

I want to generate RSA key pair and then generate the signature SHA256RSA using RSA private key and my payload. Then submit the signature and public key to java backend. Java uses my public key and signature and decrypts my payload. I want to do this in iOS swift.

This is my equivalent Android code. I need some similar solution for iOS swift.

```
import java.security.*  
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec.  
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec.  
import java.util.*  
import javax.crypto.Cipher

//Code for generating RSA Key pair  
fun generateKeyPair(): Map<String, String>? {  
        val keys: MutableMap<String, String> = HashMap()  
        var b64PublicKey = ""  
        var b64PrivateKey = ""  
        val keyGen: KeyPairGenerator  
        try {  
            keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA")  
            keyGen.initialize(1024)  
            val keyPair = keyGen.genKeyPair()  
            val publicKey = keyPair.public.encoded   
            b64PublicKey = Base64.encodeToString(publicKey, Base64.DEFAULT)  
            val privateKey = keyPair.private.encoded  
            b64PrivateKey = Base64.encodeToString(privateKey, Base64.DEFAULT)  
        } catch (e: NoSuchAlgorithmException) {  
            e.printStackTrace()  
        }  
        keys["publicKey"] = b64PublicKey  
        keys["privateKey"] = b64PrivateKey  
        Log.d("Base public and private", keys.toString())  
        return keys  
    }  
    
//Code for generating Signature  
fun signSHA256RSA(input: String, strPk: String): String? {  
    try {  
        val b1: ByteArray = decode(strPk, Base64.DEFAULT)  
        val spec = PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(b1)  
        val kf: KeyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")  
        val privateSignature: Signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA")  
        privateSignature.initSign(kf.generatePrivate(spec))  
        privateSignature.update(input.toByteArray(charset("UTF-8")))  
        val s: ByteArray = privateSignature.sign()  
        return Base64.encodeToString(s, Base64.DEFAULT)  
    }​​​​​​​​catch (e:Exception) {  
        e.printStackTrace()  
        Log.d("RAS Exception", e.printStackTrace().toString())  
    }  
    return ""  
}
```

I have tried with this iOS code. But java server not accepting signature generated by this code. And java server accepts the signature generated by Android.

```
import Security

@available(iOS 10.0, *)  
class RSAGenerator   
{  
    private var publicKey : SecKey?   
    private var privateKey : SecKey?  
     
    //code for generating RSA key pair
    func generateKeys()  -> String?
    {
        var publicKeyString : String?
        var privateKeyString : String?

        //generate a new keypair
        let parameters : [String : AnyObject] =
        [
            kSecAttrKeyType as String : kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
            kSecAttrKeySizeInBits as String : 1024 as AnyObject,
        ]
        let status = SecKeyGeneratePair(parameters as CFDictionary, &publicKey, &privateKey)
        let status1 = SecKeyGeneratePair(parameters as CFDictionary, &publicKey, &privateKey)

        //---Save your key here--- //
         
        //Convert the SecKey object into a representation that we can send over the network
        if status == noErr && publicKey != nil
        {
            if let cfData = SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation(publicKey!, nil)
            {
                let data = cfData as Data
                publicKeyString = data.base64EncodedString()
            }
        }
        
        
        if status1 == noErr && privateKey != nil
        {
            if let cfData = SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation(privateKey!, nil)
            {
                let data = cfData as Data
                privateKeyString = data.base64EncodedString()
                print(privateKeyString)

            }
        }
        
         
        print(publicKeyString)
        return publicKeyString
    }
     
    //code for generating signature
    func generateSignature(_ string : String) -> String?
    {
        var signature : String?
         
        let fileData = Data(string.utf8) //kSecPaddingNone
        
            if (privateKey != nil)
            {
                //hash the message first
                let digestLength = Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH)
                let hashBytes = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: digestLength)
                CC_SHA256([UInt8](fileData), CC_LONG(fileData.count), hashBytes)
                 
                //sign
                let blockSize = SecKeyGetBlockSize(privateKey!) //in the case of RSA, modulus is the same as the block size
                var signatureBytes = [UInt8](repeating:0, count:blockSize)
                var signatureDataLength = blockSize
                let status = SecKeyRawSign(privateKey!, .PKCS1SHA256, hashBytes, digestLength, &signatureBytes, &signatureDataLength)
                if status == noErr
                {
                    let data = Data(bytes: signatureBytes, count: signatureDataLength)
                    signature = data.base64EncodedString()
                }
            }
        print(signature)

        return signature
    }
    
}
```

I am looking for similar solution like Android for my code in swift iOS.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you matched the keys values generated by android code is similar in range or not?

Comment: What exactly server responding with the pair you have sent using this swift code please mention..

Comment: No it is not similar. iOS public key 188 characters. Android public key 216 characters. iOS private key 812 characters.  Android private key 848 characters @Abhishek

Comment: I get invalid Signature error from server side and  "errors": [
        {
            "defaultMessage": "request Wrong signature."
        }, {} ] @Abhishek